# ZFS missing filesystem after interrupted backup

Tags: backup, filesystems, zfs, zfsonlinux, lost

I have two filesystems in a pool, backup/nextcloud and backup/vm. Today, after a send/receive transfer was interrupted before it could finish (I was backing stuff up to these filesystems), I no longer see backup/vm, but the space it was taking up is still not freed up (and therefore I hope it can be easily brought back).

`zfs list` output:

```
NAME               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup             613G  2.91T      104K  /backup
backup/nextcloud   613G  2.91T      607G  /backup/nextcloud
```

`zpool status`:

```
  pool: backup
 state: ONLINE
config:

    NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    backup                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      wwn-0x5000c500c00fffbf  ONLINE       0     0     0
      wwn-0x5000c500c010b173  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

`zfs history backup` (relevant last few days):

```
2021-02-25.21:58:11 zfs create backup/vm
2021-02-25.22:50:52 zfs recv -Fu backup/vm
2021-02-26.12:01:13 zfs snapshot -r backup/nextcloud@20210226
2021-02-26.12:03:15 zfs recv -Fu backup/vm
2021-02-26.14:46:05 zfs send -RI backup/vm@20210221 backup/vm@20210226
2021-02-27.12:01:23 zfs snapshot -r backup/nextcloud@20210227
2021-02-27.12:04:04 zfs recv -Fu backup/vm
2021-02-28.12:29:55 zfs recv -Fu backup/vm
2021-02-28.14:11:35 zfs send -RI backup/vm@20210226 backup/vm@20210228
2021-02-28.14:12:38 zfs snapshot -r backup/nextcloud@20210228
2021-02-28.16:41:44 zfs send -RI backup/nextcloud@20210221 backup/nextcloud@20210228
2021-03-01.12:00:19 zfs snapshot -r backup/nextcloud@20210301
2021-03-01.15:56:15 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
2021-03-01.18:05:58 zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
```

I've tried rebooting, reimporting, and everything similar sanity passes, but to no avail.

Edit: added `zfs history backup` output

What could be done to bring back the filesystem? (zfs version 2.0.3_5.11.1.arch1.1-1)

Comment: What did this all look like before? Can you show us `zpool history backup` ?

Comment: I added the relevant parts of the output to the original post.

Comment: Where did you receive `backup/vm` from?  If that receive is the one that wasn't complete, it's likely the partially-received copy was removed as it was incomplete when the receive operation was interrupted and you can just re-`recv` it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what the *before* state was.